# select all checkbox in advanceddatagrid flex headerrenderer

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer, renderer, advanceddatagrid

I am trying to have a "Select/DeselectAll"checkbox in an advanced data grid column in flex.

```
<mp:Table id="dataTable" dataProvider="{rpadata}">
            <mp:columns>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="selected" textAlign="center" minWidth="36" width="36" paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0" sortable="false">
                    <mx:headerRenderer>
                        <mx:Component>
                            <mx:CheckBox/>
                        </mx:Component>
                    </mx:headerRenderer>
                    <mx:itemRenderer>
                        <mx:Component>
                            <mx:CheckBox width="18" click="{data.selected = !data.selected}" label="" paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0"/>
                        </mx:Component>
                    </mx:itemRenderer>
                </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Name" minWidth="260" dataField="Name"/>
            </mp:columns>
        </mp:Table>
```

For some reason, nothing gets displayed on the window for this code. Not sure what's wrong on this code. 
any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Wrapping the  with  solved the issue

Comment: Hi, can you share your solution?